# Property 'a' doesn't exist error in React native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native

[Attachment of error Image along with error on Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyMJV.png)

```
This error is located at:
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

This is what it shows at the end

Tried re-building the application on the simulator as well as Android phone. I hope to  get this problem solved.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. Find information here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how to ask a good question. With the information you provided, it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use standard html tags inside a react native application, so since `<a>` is a standard html tag you cannot use that to link the user to webpages.

If you're trying to create a link within your application you should use a standard button which then calls the `await Linking.openURL(url);` function of the react-native package.
So something like this:

```
import {Button, Linking} from 'react-native';

function LinkTestComponent() {

    function handleLinkClick(url) {
        //...
        await Linking.openURL(url);
    }

    return (

        //...
        <Button onClick={() => handleLinkClick('https://someurl')}>Link here</Button>   
    );
}
```